# Can I get value as number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few elements with numeric IDs. Each ID is in a separate span. Can I get that value as a number in order to increment? I tries as text but it does not seem to work...

```
var lastVal = $(".myID:last").text(); 
var newVal  = lastVal++;

Value <span class="myID">5</span>
```

Answer (score 10):

Convert a string to a number in js like so:

```
var num = parseInt(lastVal, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you get the `.text()` of an element, jQuery returns a string. You can't increment a string, so you'll have to make it an integer using the `parseInt()` function:

```
var lastVal = parseInt($(".myID:last").text(), 10);
```

Now `lastVal` contains an integer.

Comment: You need a radix, in case the value is `077`.

Comment: Doesn't the radix default to `10`? Oh well, I'll include it.

Comment: Not quite.  `parseInt('0777')` returns `511`.

Comment: That `0` is causing it to be interpreted as an octal number. I wish JavaScript was more stupid and interpreted things as base-10 unless you specifically told it not to...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `parseInt` function to convert it from a string to a number:

```
var newVal  = parseInt(lastVal, 10);
newVal++;
```

The second parameter to `parseInt`, `radix`, is optional and is used specify the base of your input string. Failure to supply this parameter causes the base to be determined automatically according to the following rules:

- If the string begins with "0x", the base is assumed to be 16.
- If the string begins with "0", the base is assumed to be 8.
- If the string begins with anything else, the base is assumed to be 10.

Comment: You can't `++` a return value.  Also, you need a radix.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to a number, you can use the `parseInt` function. But to actually change it (if I understand your intent correctly), you want to do:

```
var elem = $('.myID');
var num = parseInt(elem.text());
elem.text(num+1)

// <span class="myID">5</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple things here:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   var lastVal = parseInt($("#txt").val(), 10); 
   var newVal  = ++lastVal;
})
```

1. You can use parseInt to get the numeric value from the text
2. Try pre-incrementing opposed to post here. Using post increment, you're assigning the value of `lastVal` to `newVal` and *then* incrementing (which doesn't get added). Using pre increment, you modify the value of `lastVal` *before* assignment (which is what you're looking to do).

**[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/KNPkd/)**